# Why isn't my script processing all the elements in the array?

Tags: arrays, perl, push, while-loop

The following code is a test to test what I have already done with my new found knoledge of threads.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use URI;
use URI::http;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use HTML::Parser;
use LWP::Simple;
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
$ua->max_redirect(0);

print "Starting main program\n";

my @urls = ('http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk', 'http://www.1st4pets.com', 'http://www.special4you.com');
my @threads;
while ( @urls ) {
        my $url = shift ( @urls );
        my $t = threads->new(\&scan, $url);
        push(@threads,$t);
}
while (@threads) {
        my $url_thread = shift(@threads)->join;
}
sub resolve_href {
    my ($base, $href) = @_;
    my $u = URI->new_abs($href, $base);
    return $u->canonical;   
}
sub redirect_test {
    my $url = shift;
    my $redirect_limit = 10;
    my $y = 0;
    my( $response, $responseCode );
    while( 1 && $y le $redirect_limit ) {
        $response = $ua->get($url);
        $responseCode = $response->code;
        if( $responseCode == 200 || $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
            if( $responseCode == 301 || $responseCode == 302 ) {
                $url = resolve_href( $url, $response->header('Location') );
            }else{
                last;
            }
        }else{
            last;
        }
        $y++;
    }
    return ($url, $response, $responseCode, $redirect_limit, $y );
}
sub scan {
        my $url = shift;
        my @hrefs_found;
        print "started scanning: $url\n";
        my $info = URI::http->new($url);
        # if url is not an absolute url
        if( ! defined( $info->host ) ) {
            print "Invalid URL: $url \n";    
        }else{
             my $host = $info->host;
            $host =~ s/^www\.//;
            # check to see if url is valid, checks for redirects (max of 10)
            my @urlI = redirect_test( $url );
            my $content = '';
            # checks to see if url did not redirect more than 10 times and that response returned was 200
            if( $urlI[4] != $urlI[3] && $urlI[2] == 200 ) { 
                $content = $urlI[1]->content;
                die "get failed: " . $urlI[0] if ( ! defined $content );
            }
            # sticks all hrefs on a page in an array
            my @pageLinksArray = ( $content =~ m/href=["']([^"']*)["']/g );
            # foreach links found
            foreach( @pageLinksArray ) {
                # make href an absolute url
                my $url_found = resolve_href( $urlI[0], $_ );
                # check if url looks like a valid url
                if( $url_found =~ m/^http:\/\// ) {
                    my $info = URI::http->new($url_found);
                    # check to see if url is a valid url
                    if( ! defined( $info->host ) ) {
                        print "Invalid URL: $url_found \n";    
                    }else{
                        my %values_index;
                        @values_index{@hrefs_found} = ();
                        my %values_index2;
                        @values_index2{@urls} = ();
                        # if url is not already been found
                        if( ! exists $values_index{$url_found} && ! exists $values_index2{$url_found} ) {
                            # add to arrays
                            push( @hrefs_found, $url_found );
                            push( @urls, $url_found );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            print "$url found " . scalar @hrefs_found . "\n";

        }
        return $url;
}
```

The problem being, near the end of the script the new found urls are added into the arrays but the code at the top of the script is not processing them i.e. it is only going through the first test urls.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Regards,

Phil

EDIT ********

I have tried to pause it by doing something like this:

```
while ( @urls ) {
my $url = shift ( @urls );
my $t = threads->new(\&scan, $url);
push(@threads,$t);
my $n = 0;
while( 1 ) {
    if( scalar @urls == 1 ) {
        sleep 10;
    }else{
        last;
    }
    if( $n >= 1 ) {
        print "IN ARRAY URLS:\n\n";
        print @urls;
        print "\n\n";
        die "Process taking too long.";
        last;
    }
    $n++;
}
```

}

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

the result being:

```
Starting main program
started scanning: http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk
started scanning: http://www.1st4pets.com
http://www.actwebdesigns.co.uk found 24
http://www.1st4pets.com found 17
IN ARRAY URLS:

http://www.stackoverflow.com

Process taking too long. at C:\perlscripts\thread.pl line 38.
Perl exited with active threads:
        0 running and unjoined
        2 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you reduce your problem to a minimal script that demonstrates the problem. Most people aren't going to want to go through your long, complicated scripts with all sorts of other things going on. If you ask better questions, more people will be interested in helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i can see, you're starting a thread to get each URL in the original list, look through it, and add the URLs found to the original list.

Problem is, all that getting and matching takes a while, and the loop that starts the threads will likely be done well before the first new URLs get added.  It's not looking at the list again after that point, so the new URLs won't be processed.

For reference, you really ought to have some kind of synchronization and signaling going on.  Most languages do this using mutexes, "conditions", or semaphores.  Til you do something like that, you'll basically have to run your while loop over and over after you join each batch of threads from the previous while loop.

Actually...

Looking over the docs, i find [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Making-your-module-threadsafe):

> Since 5.6.0, Perl has had support for a new type of threads called interpreter threads (ithreads). These threads can be used explicitly and implicitly.
>
> Ithreads work by cloning the data tree so that no data is shared between different threads.

Good news / bad news time.  The good news is you don't have to worry about thread-safe access to `@urls` as it first appeared.  The bad news is the reason for that:  Each thread has a different `@urls`, so you can't share data between them like that without some extra help.

What you'll probably want to do instead is create the thread in list context, and let it return the list of URLs it found, which you can then append to @urls when you `join` the thread.  The alternative (sharing `@urls` between threads) could get ugly fast, if you're not aware of thread safety issues.

However you do it, it's going to cause the script to eat up a huge amount of resources -- just the three test urls contained 42 other URLs, and a bunch of them likely have URLs of their own.  So if you're going to start one thread per request, you'll very quickly end up creating more threads than just about any machine can handle.

Comment: is there anyway I can pause the first loop if there is only 1 entry left in?

Comment: it seems like its not pushing the urls

Comment: There's that, and the fact that data is not being shared between the threads.

Comment: I was getting to that.  :)  Just looking through some docs and testing stuff.

Comment: ok, so just from what you've written, are we safe to say that even if I do share the @urls to the threads its going to overload anyway...

Comment: Unless you set up a bunch of constantly running background threads, or just start less than (some number) threads each time, yeah -- 3 turns into 42, which could turn into hundreds...then thousands...if your script is still alive at that point, it'll be eating up the majority of your RAM just in thread stacks.  You can decrease the thread stack size (it starts out insanely high), but really, you're just delaying the inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each thread has its own private copy of data. That is, when you add new elements to `@urls` in one thread, the copy of `@urls` in all the other threads do not get updated, including the copy in the "parent" thread/process.

When you're ready to open another can of worms, check out the [`threads::shared`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads%3a%3ashared) module, which provides a clunky but useable way to share data between threads.